# Android app not running; java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android

I've searched around a bit and couldn't find anything relevant to my question or it didn't work. Anyways I'm getting an error message saying `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` when I try running my app on my Android phone. There is plenty of space left on the phone so I don't see why there should be an error.

Comment: Bitmaps can very easily exhaust an app's memory budget as the exception has shown, however i can refer you to a link on handling bitmaps efficiently?

Comment: This is not about storage space.  It is about the amount of memory that your app is using.  And it most likely is a problem with the way that the app is managing images; i.e. a bug in your code.  But we can't really help you fix that without seeing the relevant parts of the source code.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw Yes please, and thank you for your response!

Comment: here you go, i hope it helps https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/index.html

Comment: your image is too big to load. Try to sample it down first.

Comment: @KingfisherPhuoc what do you mean "same it down" using what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be more carefull about the of bitmap you are using in app. You must also aware of other general performance improvement tips.
You can find in developer site how to scale a bitmap.
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html 
From this link you may get help to load large image.

Another possible solution is use of some image loader libraries like Glide, Picasso or UIL etc.

You can also find some helpfull tips to reduce memory usage from here......
https://lalitjadav.blogspot.in/2017/02/best-practices-for-memory-management.html?m=1

Comment: I'm not using any bitmaps.. all I'm using are regular .png images. https://gyazo.com/ebf913685064042f69ac50a8219a2d15

Comment: Ao your png may be large. Please use image after scalling it.

Comment: What is after scaling?